# How to write a pandas dataframe as a table into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, pymysql

Just a quick question guys: I created a darabase in mysql (opinions):

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| opinions           |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

I also have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|', names=['id', 'opinions'])
df.head(3)
```

Out:

```
    id content
0   id1 'blablababla
1   id2 'blalbabla
...
n   idn 'blalbabl
```

Then, I would like to load `df` as a table (`items`) into `opinions` database. This is what I tried:

```
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@localhost:3306/opinions', echo=False)
df.to_sql(name='items', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
df
```

However, I got this exception:

```
OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 32 Broken pipe
```

How should I load or write as a table `df` into `opinions` database?

Comment: your problem is with reading the database, not writing to it

Comment: Thanks for the help @PaulH, Could you provide an example of how to do it correctly?.

Comment: Maybe help [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) and `cnx = pymysql.connect(user='user',
      password='pw',
      host= '127.0.0.1',
      port=3306,
      db='mydb',
      autocommit=True)
df=psql.read_sql_query('call sproc', con=cnx)`

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the feedback, I tried with your approach and I got: `OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22279428/2901002).

Comment: Did you actually create a table in the database, If not, Then the problem is not pandas its your knowledge of databases in general, I would go learn about basic database use, then tackle the above problem. If you did did create table in MySQL, show the 'create table' sql above.

Comment: Yes, the table name is opinions2. I also created another table: `items`. I just want to learn how to write it.... This is just an example, is not a real case @Merlin

Answer (score 2):

On your MySQL Server `opinions` is not a `table`, but a `database` (as `show databases` implies), which is basically a collection of tables. You can issue select statements only on tables however.

You can check which tables e.g. exist via `SHOW TABLES IN opinions`.
It's also convenient to add the database as an argument to the connection:

```
config = {
    'user' : 'root',
    'passwd' : 'password',
    'host' : 'localhost',
    'raise_on_warnings' : True,
    'use_pure' : False,
    'database' : 'opinions'
    }
con = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

This results in all table references to be targeted at tables in the `opinions` database.
A plain select on an **existing** table should then work:

```
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM <some_table_name>', con)
```

Comment: This actually worked. However, I still can not load the dataframe to the database as a table, neither insert the dataframe to the table:`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, opinions]
Index: []`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `pandas` - but did you actually retrieve any results with the `read_sql` call? Also: If my answer helped you out, please accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the help sebastian, I will accept your answer. One more thing, I tried the following: `df.to_sql(name = 'opinions2', con = con, flavor='mysql', schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)`.  However when I describe it with sql the table is empty... how should I load the dataframe to the database as a new table or overwrite it to an existing table?

Comment: Well if the table is empty you'll have to fill in some data first. You could e.g. create a dataframe with some arbitrary data (matching your table definition) and insert that into your database. Maybe you should also think about what you're actually trying to accomplish (reading data from sql and trying to insert it right back in doesn't make that much sense after all...)

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas to read from MySQL.  MySQLdb to write to database.

```
  mysql> show databases;
    +--------------------+
    | Database           |
    +--------------------+
    | information_schema |
    | mysql              |
    | opinions           |
    | performance_schema |
    | sys                |
    +--------------------+
```

Great!  For your example, replace `test` with `opinions`

```
mysql> use test;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+-----------------+
| _t              |
| food            |
| food_in         |
| food_min        |
| type            |
| user            |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.food;
+----+-------+--------------+--------+----------+
| ID | Cat   | Item         | price  | quantity |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | Food  | Pizza        | 2.7500 |      300 |
|  2 | Liq   | Beer         | 2.5000 |      300 |
|  4 | Food  | Sandwich     | 4.0000 |      222 |
| 12 | Food  | Soup         | 3.5000 |      100 |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So:

```
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM opinions', con)
```

Turns into:

```
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM opinions.MYTABLETHATIWANT', con)
```

I use MySQLdb to write to database. So, I can use basic python and pandas. 
You may also have permission problems that inhibits database/table access. Are you using root,  or another user and have set the permission for user.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Could you provide an example of how to write it?.

Comment: @ml_student  write what?

Comment: A pandas dataframe `df`, assuming I all ready have one... Actually I allready have a dataframe with data... I just omitted it for space issues...

Comment: You are still not telling me what you would like to help you write? Update the question above

Comment: I updated the status of the question, thanks for the help

Comment: I see you are using 'root' on MySQL. Stop it!-- create a user and use that user. Did you read the docs on pandas writing to database. I dont use pandas to write to MySQL. Sorry, Not much help there --